# Download file from URL, then save to user computer via dialog

Tags: javascript, php, web

How can I download file (I just know the URL - the file can have x MB) and then save via dialog to user computer? (Dialog = user can choose the directory, where he want to save the file). Just like in screen.

[image]

I have absolutely no idea how to do it. I Google it and I found only how to load the file via FILE input, but I do not need that.

File suffix is "*.db", thanks guys, I'm not such a web guy.

Comment: The browser already has an option, in the user settings, where they want to store their downloaded file(s). The user settings can also be set to ask the user where they want to store the file on each download. In other words it has already been done - don't fight the browser as you'll end up losing :-)

Comment: Yeah, but user can have his "download" folder, that's good :D. Bud I need to save file to his SD card. :-D So he would not have to search the downloads folder and move it manually. I saw "save dialog" just in flash now, so in javascript is not probably posible

Comment: Users can right-click a link and choose "save link as" (or similar wording) to open a file save dialog for the link's `href` file. It is not possible to specifically open this dialog (as opposed to what they have set in their preferences) for them from javascript.

Comment: @ТомасПетр flash is not supported by a lot of browsers as there are too many security issues with this product. You are trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. Let the user decide where they want to put the file. What if they do not have an SD card? What if the SD card isn't the same drive letter that you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that pretty easily.

Make a php file, let's call it `index.php`. And this should be all the code you need:

```
<?php
$file = "/your/location/file.db"; 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='" . basename($file) . "'"); 
readfile ($file);
?>
```

I hope I've understood what you actually need. This should do the trick.

Comment: This method only downloads a file, I can do it in HTML or JS. You don't see the dialog? I want the dialog on the printscreen. :-) The downloading process don't have a 1. priority. Primarily I need to choose the path where user want to save the file.

Comment: That depends on browser settings, which only the user can change.

Comment: Yeah I see, but how is it, that Flash can do it?

Comment: [A plugin is a native code library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Plugins/Guide/Plug-in_Basics#Understanding_the_Plug-in_API) is how Flash can do it. It is also why I have Flash disabled.